# How to find a string in a log file and return the entire row

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying find a processID in a log file and then return the entire line from the log file for that processID, so I can put it into an email.

An excerpt from the log is below for reference.

```
2015-02-24 11:02:27.214+0000 INFO  {anon@notarealcompany.com:ff8080814b797e84014bbb40924a1991} [SCRIPTING_LOG] [Workflow Run (2/24/15 11:02:26)] Task ID is: 56214163
```

"ff8080814b797e84014bbb40924a1991" is the processID.

I can get the javascript to return all the processIDs that it finds in the log file but can't figure out how to return the entire line.

```
// gets workflow ids from the scripting.log file and lists them
var fr = new FileReader("scripting.log");
fr.open();
var complete = fr.readAll();
var re = new RegExp(processID, 'g');
var result = complete.match(re);
var listResult = result.join("\n");
System.log("Results: " + listResult);
```

Any help would be greatfully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.*` before and after to the regex pattern variable `processID`. So that it would do a whole line match or otherwise it would do a particular substring match.

```
var re = new RegExp(".*?" + processID + ".*", 'g');
```

Comment: `var re = new RegExp("^.*?" + processID + ".*$", 'gm');`